# Linear functionals which share the properties of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

In my multi-dimensional real analysis class, we have recently defined the definite integral over $\mathbb{R}$ as so:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define the support of $f$, $supp(f)$, to be the closure of the set $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n:f(x) \neq0 \rbrace$. If $supp(f)$ is compact, we write $f\in C_{00}(\mathbb{R^n})$.
>
> Let $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ denote the familiar Riemann integral. If $f\in C_{00}(\mathbb{R})$, then there exist real numbers $a$,$b$ such that $supp(f)\subseteq [a,b]$. Let $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f =\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$ for any such $a$, $b$.

We then showed that:

> $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f+g)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f+\int_{\mathbb{R}} g$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \alpha f=\alpha\int_{\mathbb{R}} f$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. This proves that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}: C_{00}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
> is a linear functional

We haven't really discussed what a "functional" is, but I assume it is a function which acts on other functions.

Finally, we showed that:

> (1) If $f(x) \geq0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \geq 0$, (2) $|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|$, and (3) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-c)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

According to my lecturer, the definite integral is the only linear functional which also satisfies properties (1), (2), and (3), up to a multiplicative constant. I was surprised at this, and am wondering what background one needs to prove this; I assume functional analysis is needed (which I can't take yet).

Comment: This basically follows from Riesz representation theorem. You do not really need functional analysis-RRT is covered in most measure theory courses, towards the end.

Comment: To be precise, it is the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem (bad communication among different groups at the time!) that asserts that any "(positive? continuous... what topology?) functional on the LF space of compactly-supported continuous functions is given by a measure. Yes, this is usually attempted with a grossly inadequate set-up... The translation-invariance, both existence and uniqueness, are a somewhat different point. The existence is not hard in concrete cases. Uniqueness of "invariant functionals" (especially on test functions...) is non-trivial, and ... [contd]

Comment: [continuation] not usually covered "even" in functional analysis courses, which usually do not substantially develop these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_{00}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is a linear space under natural operations: The sum of two functions is defined as $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and the scalar multiple of a function is defined as $(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha f(x)$. With these operations you have a linear space. A linear functional on this space is a linear function $F : C_{00}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. "Functional" is a word reserve for a (linear) function on a linear space whose values are in the scalar field of the linear space. The integral is a functional because it takes functions and returns a scalar value, which is the integral of the function.

I suppose you could consider the result one of Functional Analysis, but I would consider the result one of measure theory, too. That's a mix. The only translation invariant, order preserving, positive linear functional is--up to a positive constant--integration with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Where Functional Analysis comes into play is showing that the only continuous linear functionals on $C_{00}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ are related to integration with respect to signed regular measures.

Comment: _Continuity_ of functionals really does matter... and "measure theory" does not come close to explaining what the topology might be on the space of continuous, compactly-supported (real-valued, or complex-valued) functions on the real line... It would be misleading to suggest to people that answers to such questions are to be found in the usual measure-theory texts, or "real analysis" texts... unfortunately.

Comment: @paulgarrett For positive functionals on vector lattices, needed continuity may be expressed entirely in terms of monotonicity. Translation invariance can be applied to a measure without continuity.

Comment: Tastes vary, but to my mind "monotonicity on a lattice [sic]" is not very _explanatory_. As in "I'd encourage my competitors to take that viewpoint"... Naturally occurring spaces of functions do have topologies, and integrals and other functionals and linear maps are continuous... "Functional analysis" can connote many things, and be inflated to something unreasonable, but I do honestly think that many such questions are only _sensibly_ answerable in a context of topologies on spaces of functions. I know, people have other opinions...

Comment: @paulgarrett : I wasn't suggesting the problem did not belong to both, but rather that it was hard to see exactly where that particular one does belong. Remember, Marshall Stone developed the theory of integrals on lattices, and that remains one of the most effective tools for proving the Riesz Representation Theorem for continuous linear functionals on $C(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a Compact Hausdorff Space. That one is a mix. Measure theory is not entirely subsumed by Functional Analysis or the other way around. Monotonicity and positivity are interesting aspects of the problem at hand, too.

Comment: I disagree, but perhaps in a way irrelevant to most of the questioner's purposes/needs.

Comment: @paulgarrett : It's almost impossible to separate the various tools of Analysis. Lebesgue's theory of measure came directly out of studying the convergence of Fourier expansions. The original tools and definitions of Topology also grew out studying the same types of problems, as well as the convergence of iterated integral expansions. It's all part of Analysis, and it's hard for me to treat the subjects as black-and-white distinctly separated. I've never been a fan of one to the exclusion of another, especially when the overlap has always been so significant.